# Android WebView onLoadResource() with only images

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Webviews `onLoadResource()` method is called when there's a resource to be downloaded. I've a situation where I need to get all the image resources in a webview. The content in the webview is dynamic, I can enter google.com/anyurl in a webview and the `onLoadResource()` is called where I am getting `CSS Sprite images, Javascript Files` and other irrelevent files.

- Is there a way to check if the url from `onLoadResource()` is called from `DOM Body` and is there a way to eliminate downloading js files and css sprite images ?
- Is there a way to access the webview cached resources so I could just access the downloaded images instead of redownloading it ?